# Loading 2D raw data

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I've obtained a 2D map from another development environment, how could I load/display/manipulate (in gazebo/rviz) this set of 2D points.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9611/loading-2d-raw-data/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-03-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-03-31**:
I've the 2D coordinate points in a .txt file.

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-03-31**:
What format is your map in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the simplest way is to write your map to a .pgm file. I guess a simple program can do it. It has to map the occupied points to black pixels (value=0), the free points to white pixels (254) and unknown points to gray pixels (205).

Then you can use the map_server package to publish it to rviz with the command:
rosrun map_server map_server mymap.pgm

If you set the fixed frame as "/map" in rviz, you should see your map.

Hope this helps,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-04-01**:
I've plot my map in Matlab, saved it in .tif and convert it into .pgm. The map is successfully loaded into RViz . Thank you!

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2015-01-29**:
I know this is an old thread, but I cant get this method to work. I have the pgm file on my desktop, and I run  rosrun map_server map_server mymap.pgm, but it cant open the file. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-06-11**:
I used `rosrun map_server map_server` rospack find <my_map_package>`/mymap.yaml`.

Be sure you have the correct file_path within the argument for your mymap.yaml

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-06**:
The command is `rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml` not `rosrun map_server map_server mymap.pgm`